# Lazyload image in Vue/Nuxt gallery component

Tags: image, vue.js, nuxt.js, lazy-loading, gallery

I'm trying to create a simple gallery component where if you click on some image a Light-Box will appear where you can see full size photo and have options like next and previous photo or close the Light-Box.

Currently When I need to change the image to next or previous I change the **src** of the img-tag and it works.

Here comes my problem. I want to lazy load my images. I use [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) in my project.
So the simple implementation to have an image to load is to add the class "lazyload" and to pass the property **data-src** instead of **src**.

However if I change to **data-src** my methods for next and previous image are not working.

```js
< script >
  export default {
    props: {
      data: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    data: () => ({
      visible: false,
      currentImage: 0,
    }),
    methods: {
      Toggle(index) {
        this.currentImage = index
        this.visible = !this.visible
      },
      Next() {
        if (this.currentImage !== this.data.length - 1) this.currentImage++
      },
      Prev() {
        if (this.currentImage !== 0) this.currentImage--
      },
    },
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
  
    <!-- images grid -->
        <div v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="'gallery-image' + i" class="image">
            <img :src="item.image.thumbnail.url" @click.native="Toggle(i)" class="lazyload"/>
        </div>
    
    
    <!-- image lighbox on click -->
      <div v-if="visible" class="lightbox">
          <Icon class="cancel" @click="Toggle()"/>
          <Icon name="left" :class="{ disable: currentImage == 0 }"  @click="Prev()"/>
      <img :src="data[currentImage].image.url" class="lazyload"/> 
          <Icon name="right" :class="{ disable: currentImage == data.length - 1 }" @click="Next()"/>
      </div>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

***UPDATE***
I forgot to add crucial code. To implement lazysizes in a Nuxt project we need to add in nuxt.config.js the fallowing code. You can read more [here](https://dev.to/ignore_you/minify-generate-webp-and-lazyload-images-in-your-vue-nuxt-application-1ilm).

```js
build: {
  extend(config, { isClient, loaders: { vue } }) { 
    vue.transformAssetUrls.img = ['data-src', 'src']
  },
},
```

As I investigate in the developer tools I found that when triggering click for method like Next image, the src of the image does not change, only the data-src. I'm guessing I need a way to trigger this transform so that everything can work as expected.

Comment: There is a lot here. Try to narrow it down because `lazysizes` is probably not the biggest library that everybody uses. To answer your question, somebody will need to understand how this specific library works, try to guess what is happening on the network and at the same time, does this in the context of a lightbox. So yeah, basically consulting. Try to update your question, give it more debugging details via the devtools, explain a bit more in depth what `methods for next and previous image are not working` do mean. Also, a [repro] may maybe help here too.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try to update this question.
As you said maybe its better to look deeper in lazysizes and also  other library or even write some logic on my own about lazyload just for this component I try to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, [on top of my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814842/lazyload-image-in-vue-nuxt-gallery-component?noredirect=1#comment121623592_68814842), I do recommend looking into the official [nuxt image module](https://image.nuxtjs.org/) which do have native lazy loading out of the box: https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img

You could maybe combo this with some simple lightbox that does the trick for you. I've used [vue-silentbox](https://github.com/silencesys/silentbox) before, it is working pretty well.

You can have that kind of code there

```html
<silent-box :gallery="photosToDisplay">
  <template #silentbox-item="{ silentboxItem }">
    <img :src="silentboxItem.src" :key="silentboxItem.id" />
  </template>
</silent-box>
```

So, I guess that you could totally swap `img` by a `nuxt-img` there, and have it lazy-loaded.
The images are not lazy-loaded in the project, but [here](https://github.com/kissu/pet-friends) is a small project that I did to try out the lightbox if you want to quickly look how it renders (URL in the top right corner).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the most elegant way to do it . I [force re-render](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) to my image component. You need to assign a **key** value to component and whenever the value changes a new instance creates of the component.

Comment: Yeah, this one is pretty heavy on the webpage.